# @synchronized [UIView animationWithDuration...] lock ending?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uikit

Will the @synchronized lock  until the end of the animation?

```
__weak typeof(sharedManager) weakManager = sharedManager;

^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)         
{

@synchronized(weakManager)
             { ... some code
                 if (angle != sharedManager.angle)
                 {
                     if (sharedManager.isLocked) return;

                     sharedManager.locked = YES;

                     sharedManager.angle = angle;

                     CGAffineTransform transform = (angle == 0) ?
                     CGAffineTransformIdentity : CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                     sharedManager.currentTransform = transform;

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                                      animations:^
                     {
                         [weakManager.animatedViews setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:transform]
                                                      forKey:@"transform"];

                     }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         weakManager.locked = NO;
                     }];
                 }
             }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It will only wait for the duration of the method call. The actual animation happens a asynchronously and doesn't affect the lock.

I guess that if you wanted that behavior, you could use a NSRecursiveLock and explicitly unlock in the completion block of the animation but that's a pretty strange thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, @synchronized releases its lock when its block exits, which is before the animations here begin. But you almost never want to use @synchronized anymore in any case. It's a very expensive lock.

This code is a bit strange. Do you really want to throw away the update if the manager is currently animating? Wouldn't you want to move to the new target? That's how Core Animation normally works; you set a target, start animating, and if things change you just animate towards that new target.

---

If you want to serialize operations, which seems to be your goal, then the better tools are `NSOperation` or dispatch queues. I'd probably use a serial dispatch queue here. Put the action you want on the queue (whatever modifies `weakManager`). If you don't want any more actions to process until the animation is done, then call `dispatch_suspend` to suspend the queue, and `dispatch_resume` to start it again in the completion block.

the other potentially useful tool here is a `dispatch_sempahore`, which can be used in place of the `isLocked` property. But I'd recommend just using a queue if possible. In most cases, if you're locking in modern Cocoa, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: actually the synchronized is to protect the animatedViews from being accessed in the transition while one object might be taken out of it. this block is called twice per second and nothing else is done afterward. I guess it is okay. and yes I want to throw the update if it is animating. Thx for your answer btw

Comment: I was thinking about forcing the code on the same thread manually with a dispatch_asycn. I actually never used an @synchronized before this.

Comment: Don't think of this as "on the same thread." That may or may not be true. The point is that it will be serialized by the queue.

Comment: I ended up doing something along dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_block_t block = ^
    { //code here
    };

    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        block();
    else
        dispatch_sync(main, block);